# handle huge amount of files in directory in mathematica

Tags: for-loop, memory, memory-management, wolfram-mathematica

I have a huge amount of datafiles (.csv) saved in one directory. I want now to fit and evaluate several parameters for each file. Since there are over 300.000 files in this directory, mathematica is not able to run my script. The first attempt i tried was to set the directory to this folder and then i tried to emport each file alone through a 'For-loop' (for i=1,i<=imax,i++ *where imax is the number of files in there*), do the whole fitting evaluation etc and then starting the loop again and importing the second file,.... to save memory. Unfortunately, this approach didn't work at all and mathematica crashed almost immediately.

So, my question is now, can I handle such a huge amount of files in a single directory somehow without running out of memory?

Comment: 300,000 files is rather over the top.  Nonetheless it's not clear, without sight of code, why *Mathematica* should have crashed.  Perhaps you weren't closing each file after you were done with it and your code ran out of available file handles.  Perhaps ... well, speculation sans code is idle.

Answer (score 0):

The method below loads all the data from all the CSVs into a function variable called `data`.  So if you have CSVs called `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` their data will be loaded into variables called `data["file1.csv"]` and `data["file2.csv"]`.  Then, for example, the data in the first column of every CSV is read into a variable called `xvalues` and the data in the second column of every CSV is read into a variable called `yvalues`.

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\yourname\\datadirectory"];
files = FileNames["*.csv"];
(data[#] = Import[#]) & /@ files;

xvalues = yvalues = {};

(xvalues = Join[xvalues, data[#][[All, 1]]]) & /@ files;
xvalues = Flatten[xvalues];

(yvalues = Join[yvalues, data[#][[All, 2]]]) & /@ files;
yvalues = Flatten[yvalues];
```

A fit can then be calculated.

```
fit = Fit[Transpose[{xvalues, yvalues}], {1, x}, x]
```